# Changing display property with media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries, display

I used the following CSS code and it worked fine:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:800px)
{
  .column {
        width:30%;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2%;
   }   
}
```

But when I use the following CSS code, the `display` property didn't change, why?

```css
.column {
        width:30%;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px)
{
.column
    {
       display:block;
       background-color:turquoise;
       font-size:2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, it works fine.

Comment: It is change the `display` property. Is it visual problem you're having instead?

Comment: I just noticed that I was using 'float:left' and that's why the change wasn't apparent to blocks as they were still aligned side by side. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. You should post and accept your answer to help people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not because you have `width:30%;`. Change your code to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
       width: 100%;
       display:block;
       background-color:turquoise;
       font-size:2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was because of the float property that went unnoticed by me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written is perfectly fine. The display property is changing it's value.
The reason why the change is not apparent is because the width is still "30%" even after changing into "block" element.

Either assign it a new width like "100%", which is default for "block" elements, or some other value.

Comment: It was because of the float property that went unnoticed by me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The display property was being changed from inline block to block but because the width was 30% and **float property was set to left**, the change was not visible. When float was removed, the divs arranged themselves in separate lines, characteristic of block elements.